# Change static multiple radio buttons array to dynamic Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can I change my multiple radio buttons to dynamic?

here are my radio buttons and its value on **View**

```html
A. <input type="radio" name="quizId<?= $question->id ?>" value="<?= $ans_array[0] ?>" required /> <?= $ans_array[0] ?> <br>
B. <input type="radio" name="quizId<?= $question->id ?>" value="<?= $ans_array[1] ?>" /> <?= $ans_array[1] ?> <br>
C. <input type="radio" name="quizId<?= $question->id ?>" value="<?= $ans_array[2] ?>" /> <?= $ans_array[2] ?> <br>
D. <input type="radio" name="quizId<?= $question->id ?>" value="<?= $ans_array[3] ?>" /> <?= $ans_array[3] ?> <br>
```

and here is my **Controller** How can I fetch them dynamically? without calling every single item

```php
public function resultDisplay(){
    $this->data['checks'] = array(
        'ques1' => $this->input->post('quizId1'),
        'ques2' => $this->input->post('quizId2'),
        'ques3' => $this->input->post('quizId3'),
        'ques4' => $this->input->post('quizId4'),
        'ques5' => $this->input->post('quizId5')
    );
    $this->load->model('quiz_model');
    $this->data['results'] = $this->quiz_model->getQuestions();
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('activity/result_display', $this->data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

This gives an error

After changing my Controller to

```
$this->data['checks'] = array(
        'ques' => $this->input->post('quizId');
);
```

```
<?php 
        for($x=0; $x < 5; $x++) {
    ?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Pages/index" >


    <p><?= $array3[$x] ?>.<?= $array4[$x] ?></p>

    <?php if($array2[$x] != $array1[$x]) {?>

          <p><span class="badge" style="background-color: #FF9C9E"><?=$array1[$x]?></span></p>
          <p><span class="badge" style="background-color: #ADFFB4"><?=$array2[$x]?></span></p>

    <?php } else { ?>

        <p><span class="badge" style="background-color: #ADFFB4"><?=$array1[$x]?></span></p>

        <?php $score = $score + 1; ?>

    <?php 
        }
    }
    ?>
    <hr>

    <h5>Your score: </h5>
            <h3><?= $score ?>/5</h3>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-md" value="Back" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $i = 1;
  foreach($ans_array AS $array_value): 
?>
<?= $i; ?>.&nbsp; <input type="radio" name="quizId<?= $question->id ?>" value="<?= $array_value ?>" required /> <?= $array_value ?> <br>

<?php 
$i++; 
endforeach; 
?>
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: hello sir, how can I adjust the controller then? if i change my view foreach?

Comment: on my Controller, the `quest1-5` are the questions in array but it is static.

Comment: can you please see my edit code above there has problem occur thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using array will be more efficient. You can do it this way:

```
<input type="radio" name="quizId[<?= $question->id ?>]" value="<?= $array_value ?>" required /> <?= $array_value ?> <br />
```

So after `post` you can go throughout loop and get your post results like:

```
foreach($this->input->post('quizId') as $val){
    //work with each value here
}
```

Like i see you can update the controller this way:

```
$this->data['checks'] = $this->input->post('quizId');
```

You sent entire array to `view`. Now in the `view` file you need to specify the key value to be like `quizId . $key`.